# Is it possible to build datasets in Foundry Code Workbook via parameters in Reports?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

I would like to build a dataset in Foundry Code Workbook via a parameter in Reports.

The dataset in Code Workbook is built using a template that is configured by a parameter in Code Workbook.

I would like to add the dataset to Reports and integrate the Code Workbook parameter to Reports to trigger the build in Code Workbook. What's the best way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. To do that, you need to create a workbook level parameter and link it to your template parameter. By using workbook-level parameters, you are able to link together the values of multiple template inputs.

Charts generated in the workbook can be added to Foundry Reports for presentation and collaboration.